# Braintree Payment Gateway Failure - Magneto2 - "Something Went Wrong"

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, braintree

Problem:

**Products in Magento store cannot be processed via Braintree payment.**

Versions:

- PHP: 7.0.27
- Magento: 2.1.11

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add product to cart
2. Proceed to checkout
3. Sign in
4. Select Braintree Payment Method
5. Enter CC No. (4111111111111111) Exp Date: 02/18 CVC: 111

Result "Sorry, but something went wrong".

My understanding is that the latest version of the core Magento code is very unstable. I had no problems with this (and authorize.net)modules with previous Magento versions.

Does anyone have a solution? Otherwise, I simply cannot use my store.

Comment: Can you check this bug reported on GitHub, Maybe you can get a hint how to debug the issue you are facing:-

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had this happen to me, the advanced setting for the account was that of production not of the sandbox, remove this to use default or add the one from the sandbox account.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the issue was because I put the wrong Merchant Account ID under Advanced Settings. I assumed that Merchant ID was equivalent to Merchant Account ID, but no, they're two different things.

You can get your Merchant ID on the dashboard of the Braintree sandbox.

You can get your Merchant Account ID through Account -> Merchant Account Info -> Merchant Account ID. If you only have one merchant account, you can leave the value blank in the configuration.

Comment: The menu title is now "Business"

Comment: Click gear icon > business

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact).</sub>

There are a few known issues with the Magento2 + Braintree module that I'm aware of, but I'd like to clear a few things up with you first.

First and foremost, the test credit card 4111111111111111 will only successfully create transactions when your Magento site is connected to a Braintree sandbox account. If your production account is connected, then it will still create a transaction/verification however it will do so unsuccessfully and with the status "Processor Declined".

As long as your sandbox API keys are connected to your Magento2 store, some general issues others have noted in the past are:

**Dynamic Descriptors**

The input for descriptors in your Magento2 store do themselves contain validations that Braintree's API has on the fields when they're passed in a Transaction.Sale() API call. As such, if you have any descriptors in place and they do not adhere to the requirements listed in our developer documentation, that could case this issue.

**Billing/Shipping Information**

This would manifest itself as a 400 error on your page in the network tab so it's unlikely you're seeing this, but there was a known issue where the state/region portion of the checkout page would cause a 400 error to be passed back. If it happens it should appear in the payment-information network request during checkout

That said, if neither of those things are related to your issue please feel free to write in to our [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact) team and we can verify your Braintree account settings and see if any API activity is making it to our servers. It might also be worth it to check your system and debug logs in `/var/log`. You can enable the debug logs for your Braintree module by navigating to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Configure (Under Braintree) > Advanced Braintree Settings
and set Debug = Yes.

Finally as Keyur Shah mentioned in his comment, the magento2 github issue section is fairly well fleshed out with reported issues/solutions so I'd definitly check there as well!

Comment: Thanks - this is a Braintree sandbox account. I am not receiving a 400 error. Simply: "sorry, something went wrong" (I have enabled debug). I will contact contact the support team.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be happen due to many reasons like
- wrong parameters passed 
- incorrect credentials 
or something else.

check your log files and also while you are placing the order, open the developer window of your browser and go to network tab and then place order, after that from the list select the link where it has error or non 202 and see its params and response. From this you will get an idea why it was giving this error.

Comment: Thank you - notes in the Network tab point me to Interceptor.php (58). In the .php file this is   "return parent::$method(...array_values($arguments));" I see nothing wrong with this?